# Good Textbook for combined Beginning and Intermediate Algebra Course

Tags: undergraduate-education, algebra, textbooks, community-colleges

We'd like to create  a course that covers beginning and intermediate algebra in one course (8 hours a week), getting students ready to succeed in precalc and calculus. I am at a community college.

I would like textbook recommendations.

I'm not 100% sure yet of the topics. I think we'll do a tiny bit of trig, because that's the hardest thing in precalc. Something like: 
1 - Equations
2 - Graphing
3 - Multiplying and Factoring, finding zeros
4 - Rational Expressions
5 - Roots and Quadratics (also absolute value functions)
6 - Exponential Functions and Logs
7 - Geometry and Trig

Comment: I guess this varies enough, could you outline the expected topics?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure yet of the topics. I think we'll do a tiny bit of trig, because that's the hardest thing in precalc. Something like: 
1 - Equations
2 - Graphing
3 - Multiplying and Factoring, finding zeros
4 - Rational Expressions
5 - Roots and Quadratics (also absolute value functions)
6 - Exponential Functions and Logs
7 - Geometry and Trig

Answer (score 4):

I've recently switched to using OpenStax open education resources in my college algebra courses. That is, they are: Free of cost, free to redistribute, free to edit if desired. For many years I thought the quality of OER materials was unacceptably low, but in the last year or two they've crossed the threshold of usability for me. They're digital in format (web view, PDF, and other options) so I can carry them on a tablet, and also throw them on an overhead projector when desired.

[OpenStax Algebra and Trigonometry](https://openstax.org/details/algebra-and-trigonometry) has what you describe.

If not that, then I've also liked Sullivan's *Algebra and Trigonometry*, but it's a massive tome (1034 pages plus answer section and index in the 7th edition).

Comment: Is either of these lower level than precalc / college algebra?

Comment: @SueVanHattum: I suppose it's how you use it, but I think in most contexts your list of topics will by definition count as precalculus. Both of these texts have a subset-edition (without the trigonometry) called *College Algebra*. E.g.: https://openstax.org/details/college-algebra

Comment: One of the things about OER is that I feel much better about possibly only using selected parts of a large text.

Comment: But we're attempting to prepare them for precalculus. We are starting at the beginning of algebra. The only thing unusual for Beginning and Intermediate Algebra is the geometry and trig.